# Pulling changes from TFS with git-tf

Tags: tfs, git-tf

In our company, `git` is not supported, only `TFS` is. In my team however, we all use `git` and before using `git-tf` we were using `git-tfs`. A few days ago me and another colleague decided to give `git-tf` a try, so we did a `git tf clone --deep` of our project from `TFS`. That worked fine and we can see all changesets as separate commits in the treeview.

Some of our projects are shared with other teams, so other people will make changes and use only `TFS` to push their changes. What I've noticed is that even though I'm using `git tf pull --deep`, all changesets are being bundled in just one commit that contains all the files that were changed. Even if in the TFS history I can see that there were 10 changesets made by the other team in the last day for example. I'm only seeing 1 new commit in my history.

When reading the `git-tf` documentation I see this:

> Pull
>
> `git tf pull [--deep] [--rebase]`
>
> Fetches changes made in TFS as a new
>   commit in Git, and merges the commit with the latest commit in the
>   current branch. By default, the fetch performed by the pull command is
>   shallow, but the --deep option may be used to create a Git commit for
>   each TFS changeset created since the last fetch. Also, merge is used
>   by default when pulling, but the --rebase option may be used to
>   perform a rebase instead.

What am I missing? What command do I have to use in order to get each changeset as a new commit on my local `git` branch?

EDIT 1-6-2016

Since it's been quite a while since I've asked this question and no answers have been posted, this question can be closed/deleted. Maybe in a future version of `git-tfs` this will be made possible, I'll keep an eye on it.